# Stacked bar chart for a pandas df

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a df like this and would like to plot stacked bar chart where in the x axis is Component and the y-axis shows the count by 'Major', 'Minor' etc.

```
       Component Priority
0  Browse Groups    Minor
1  Notifications    Major
2             BI    Major
3             BI    Minor
4             BI    Minor
```

For example, the first bar would have 1st component with a count of 1 minor,..so on.. and 3rd would have 'BI' in x-axis with 1 count of Major and 2 counts of Minor stacked.
What is the simplest way to do this in seaborn or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) both columns and [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html?highlight=count#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count) on Priority, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.Series.unstack) and plot as stacked [`bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) chart:

```
df.groupby(['Component', 'Priority']).Priority.count().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Component': list('abccc'), 'Priority': ['Minor', 'Major', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Minor']})
df.groupby(['Component', 'Priority']).Priority.count().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

As an alternative, you can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html?highlight=crosstab#pandas.crosstab):

```
pd.crosstab(df.Component, df.Priority).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

If you want to use `seaborn` (I only now saw the seaborn tag), you can use a [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html?highlight=displot#seaborn.displot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(x='Component', hue='Priority', data=df, multiple='stack')
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! The first option you provided did the job for me. Thank you very much. Appreciate it.